# Connect a docker container with Yii to a non-linked docker container with MySQL server

Tags: docker, yii

I have a dockerized Yii project and nginx. I have a separate docker container with mysql server, which I imported a mysql dump into.

The project fails with error:

```
2018-08-15 12:34:52 [-][-][-][error][yii\db\Exception] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:687
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(687): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'user', 'pass', NULL)
.............
```

I suspect the docker services for the project were supposed to be linked in `docker-compose.yml`. Something like this:

```
version: '2'
services:

    app:
        image: app
        links:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
```

Is this possible to connect to mysql server without linking docker services? 
If yes, how can it be done?

**UPDATE 1**

my current docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

    yiiapp_nginx:
        image: nginx

        hostname: 'dev.yiiapp.com'

        depends_on:
          - yiiapp_app

        ports:
            - "80:80"

        volumes_from:
          - yiiapp_app

        volumes:
          - ./docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/
          - ./docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx

        container_name: "yiiapp_nginx"

    yiiapp_app:
        build:
            ./

        container_name: yiiapp_app

        hostname: 'dev.yiiapp.com'

        environment:

            MYSQL_DATABASE: yiiapp
            MYSQL_USER: yiiapp
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: yiiapp
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yiiapp


        volumes:
            - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
            - ./:/app
            - ./docker/container-files/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

        expose:
            - "9000"
```

**UPDATE 2**

So this is how I solved it in my case. 
For each separate `docker-compose.yml` docker actually creates a separate network. [ref](https://blog.docker.com/2016/12/understanding-docker-networking-drivers-use-cases/)

> Behind the scenes, the Docker Engine creates the necessary Linux
>   bridges, internal interfaces, iptables rules, and host routes to make
>   this connectivity possible.

So, from my local machine I can freely access both containers, but they cannot access each other. Without modifying my existing `docker-compose.yml` I ran:

```
 docker network create yiiapp_network
 docker network connect yiiapp_network mysql_container
 docker network connect yiiapp_network yiiapp_app
 docker network connect yiiapp_network yiiapp_nginx
 docker network inspect yiiapp_network
```

Which created a new network and added all containers to it.

Also, I changed the db hostname to my db container name:

```
$db_host = 'mysql_container';
```

And it worked.

Comment: So you have a altogether different mysql container running. How are you deploying `yii` project & nginx? Using `docker run` or `docker-compose`? Are all of them exist on the same host?

Comment: @vivekyad4v I use `docker-compose`, which was already written by somebody else, because this is an existing project.. And yes, I'm trying to connect to my db. Do I need to link the db service in `docker-compose.yml`? Because right now I don't have `links: - db` in my `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: If you have `db` service in the same docker compose file, you need not to externally provide any links. You can call it by name `db` from `yii` container. What's the exact connection string? make sure you use `db` as the mysql hostname in the connection string.

Comment: From where are you able to connect mysql & how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` from your application? If so, you must change it to the name of the **service running the database** in your `docker-compose`, I.E, **db**.
Seeing your error message you should have something like that instead:

```
('mysql:host=db', 'user', 'pass', NULL)
```

And be sure that the two containers are in same network so they can reach each other. 
If you don't specify specific network they'll be in same network by default and you don't need to link one to another.

EDIT after update of docker-compose

Since your database container and your application container were not running in same docker-compose and you didn't force either of them to join a specific network, they are not in same network and can't reach each other.

You don't need to expose your database port on host network if you don't want to. You can simply create a network dedicated to your application, let's call it `backend`:

```
docker network create backend
```

By default it will use the bridge driver and only containers from the same host will be able to attach to the network.

You don't need to stop your database container to attach it to the `backend` network, just run:

```
docker network connect backend <db_container_name>
```

And lastly modify your docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  yiiapp_nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: 'dev.yiiapp.com'
    depends_on:
      - yiiapp_app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes_from:
      - yiiapp_app
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/
      - ./docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
    container_name: "yiiapp_nginx"
    networks:
      - frontend

  yiiapp_app:
    build: .
    container_name: yiiapp_app
    hostname: 'dev.yiiapp.com'
    environment:
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=yiiapp
        - MYSQL_USER=yiiapp
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=yiiapp
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yiiapp
    volumes:
        - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
        - ./:/app
        - ./docker/container-files/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    expose:
        - "9000"
    network:
        - backend_network
        - frontend

networks:
  backend_network:
    external:
      name: backend

  frontend:
    name: yiiapp_frontend
    driver: bridge
```

Re-build your compose stack with `docker-compose up --build` and it should be working.

You will surely want that your mysql database container always stay in the `backend` network, so modify its `docker run script` or its `docker-compose` in the same way. See [Specify custom networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) from docker networking doc.

Comment: I think there are a few errors in your suggested config and a version mismatch, but generally speaking this is how I actually solved it. Your answer was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: I answered from my phone so indeed there should be some errors. Feel free to tell me and I will correct it. BTW I think you shouldn't have to play with hostname like you do. In fact if you use NGINX, you don't have to set any hostname in docker and it should work perfectly if you refer to container name

Comment: Don't worry about it, because your example demonstrates docker network interactions pretty well, anyone using it will still have to make changes. Basically, my task here is to add new functionality to the yii app, so I can mess up things by removing hostname myself, there's probably a reason why it's there ;) Anyway, thanks for your help again! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `db` service in the same docker compose file, you need not to externally provide any links. You can call it by name `db` from `yii` or `app`  container.  Make sure you use `db` as the mysql hostname in the connection string for `yii` or `app` service/container.

`('mysql:host=db', 'user', 'pass', NULL)`

Recreate containers -

`$ docker-compose build ; docker-compose up -d`

In case your mysql exists on the host machine, you can either put your host IP to the connection string or make use of `network_mode` (**preferred**) in your docker-compose, add below to your `app/yii` service of docker-compose & build the container again -

`network_mode: "host"`

Once you use `network_mode: "host"`, you need to change the connection string to (host=127.0.0.1, port=3306) -

`('mysql:host=127.0.0.1....', 'user', 'pass', NULL)`

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Comment: Well, it gives me `Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php:687` :) The mysql docker container is running and I can access 127.0.0.1:3306 and actually see the db with tables.

Comment: I guess that's on a different network. `127.0.0.1:3306` works from the host machine, right?

Comment: yes, for example `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306` is working ok. I think, I should add my existing `docker-compose.yml` to my question

Comment: Which means your mysql exist on the host machine itself. Updated my answer, give it a shot.